# Inner join not retrieving data from both tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables which I am pulling data from to display in amcharts. One is `packagePurchases` and the other is `productPurchases`. This is the first time I have joined tables and despite all of the reading I have done, I'm missing something. The problem is that if I run the report for today, if there are no packagePurchases, but there are productPurchases, the productPurchases are ignored.

Here is my code:

```
$selectDaysQuery = "SELECT productPurchases.purchaseDate, packagePurchases.purchaseDate 
                            FROM productPurchases INNER JOIN packagePurchases
                            ON productPurchases.purchaseDate = packagePurchases.purchaseDate
                            WHERE productPurchases.companyId = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $companyId)."' 
                            AND productPurchases.purchaseDate >= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $dateFrom)."' 
                            AND productPurchases.purchaseDate <= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $dateTo)."'
                            GROUP BY productPurchases.purchaseDate
                            ";

        if($selectDaysResult = $con->query($selectDaysQuery))
        {

            if($selectDaysResult->num_rows>0)
            {

                while($selectDaysRow = $selectDaysResult->fetch_assoc())
                {

                    $date = $selectDaysRow['purchaseDate'];

                    $joinQuery = "SELECT SUM(productPurchases.itemCost) AS productSales, 
                                         SUM(packagePurchases.packageCost) AS packageSales, 
                                             productPurchases.purchaseDate AS category 
                                         FROM productPurchases INNER JOIN packagePurchases 
                                         ON productPurchases.purchaseDate = packagePurchases.purchaseDate 
                                         WHERE productPurchases.purchaseDate = '".$date."'
                                         GROUP BY productPurchases.purchaseDate, packagePurchases.purchaseDate 
                                         ORDER BY packagePurchases.purchaseDate DESC";

                    if($joinResult = $con->query($joinQuery))
                    {

                        while($joinRow = $joinResult->fetch_assoc())
                        {

                            $data[$x]['category'] = $joinRow['category'];
                            $data[$x]['productSales'] = number_format($joinRow['productSales'], 2, '.', ',');
                            $data[$x]['packageSales'] = number_format($joinRow['packageSales'], 2, '.', ',');
                            $x++;
                        }

                    } else {

                        $data['errors'][$e] = mysqli_error($con);
                        $e++;

                    }

                }


            } else {

                $data['nodata'] = true;

            }       

        } else {

            $data['errors'][$e] = mysqli_error($con);
            $e++;


        }
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN on packagePurchases would be a good start

Comment: For SQL questions you should only post SQL queries. Not queries obfuscated as String constants in your programming language. You also need to tell us which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Noted @a_horse_with_no_name. Thankyou

Comment: Thanks @RaphaëlAlthaus. I'll start researching

Comment: @MarkBell are you sure you don't want to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` here? Using an `INNER JOIN` will ignore all days on which there were no productPackages, or no packagePurchases. Using a `productPurchases LEFT JOIN packagePurchases` will ignore all days on which there were some packagePurchases but no productPurchases

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, I feel you need to see results for a given day if there has been at least one product purchase or package purchase. This looks like a case for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, since you want all rows from both tables to show up in your result.

What an `INNER JOIN` will do, is consider only the rows that are present in both tables.

Comment: Thanks, Chitharanjan. So would I just replace my INNER JOIN with FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Yes, if I'm reading your problem statement right, then switching the `INNER JOIN` out for a `FULL JOIN` should do it.

Comment: Hmm, that returns {"errors":["Unknown column 'productPurchases.purchaseDate' in 'field list'"]. I am currently reading on UNION ALL. Am I going in the right direction?